# Mdi child forms don´t get some keystrokes

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, mdi

I have a base form class which overrides OnKeyDown and OnKeyPress methods to trap some keystrokes which are of interest in my application.

Every form has two basic states: Idle or Busy (this one when adding or updating database records ). 
So, it´s important to trap the Esc key, so if the form is idle, it gets confirmation from the user, and Closes the form; if the form is in Busy state, the keystroke is ignored.

This works fine when the derived forms runs alone. But when I open them from an MDI parent, the Esc keystroke don´t reach the active child form. Remaining keystrokes have not problem, exception is after a "failed" Esc; in this case, none of them reaches the active form.

I cannot find an explanation. May be the MDI parent form filters some  keystrokes?

TIA